# Command Line - Wait for a Process to Finish

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm installing a set of drivers in an unattended script. One of the drivers (Intel USB3 Drivers) kicks off the Windows Driver Finder application ("drvinst.exe") after it's finished. Then, when the nVidia Drivers try to run, they cancel out because that Wizard is still running in the background.

My current solution is this, but it is not very elegant:

```
:INSTALLLAPTOP79
.\ELAN\Touchpad\Setup.exe /s /a /s
.\Intel\Chipset\Setup.exe -s -norestart
.\Intel\Graphics\Setup.exe -s
.\Intel\MEI\Setup.exe -s
.\Intel\USB3\Setup.exe -s
.\Realtek\Audio\Setup.exe /s
.\Realtek\CardReader\Setup.exe /s
TIMEOUT 180
.\nVidia\Graphics\Setup.exe -n -s
GOTO :INSTALLLAPTOPWIFI
```

Basically if a system is slower than "normal" it will fail as the 180 seconds isn't enough. I could just increase this value but that is messy to me.

**I'm basically looking for a way to do a "check" to see if the "drvinst.exe" is still running** and if so wait for a set period - then do the check again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

It's not guaranteed to work (it depends on how the installers launch the driver-finder) but:

```
start /wait command...
```

may do the trick.  Be aware that if the command to be executed contains spaces, and needs to be wrapped in double-quotes, you'll need:

```
start /wait "" "c:\program files\something\..."
```

otherwise it will take the command as the title of the command-prompt.

Comment: Thanks - tried this - unfortunately the setup exits and the wait command ignores the drvinst.exe that starts.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

notepad

:waitloop

TASKLIST /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 timeout /t 1 /n&GOTO waitloop

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a simple method waiting for `notepad.exe` to close. Adapt as you will...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

notepad

:waitloop

TASKLIST |find "notepad.exe" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 timeout /t 1 /n&GOTO waitloop

GOTO :EOF
```

should work also

Comment: ok so I ran `TASKLIST |find "drvinst.exe"
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%` and the Tasklist command is correctly identifying the process but the error level came out as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: @Magoo, notsure which Windows version you tried this out with. In Windows 10 (1903) the first code always gives errorlevel 0, and the second code gives the inverse errorlevel of what you need for your code to work. I posted an answer which works in Windows 10 when saved as a .BAT file.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Windows 10 (1903). Caveat: if you use it for a process that is running multiple times, it waits for *all* of them to finish before continuing.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516904/669202) by @Magoo which didn't work for me, but put me on the right track.

```
@ECHO OFF

notepad.exe
REM For the OP's original problem, put drvinst.exe instead of notepad.exe (here and below)

:waitloop
TASKLIST |find /I "notepad.exe" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO endloop
REM echo Notepad running. Waiting 1 second...
timeout /t 1 /nobreak>NUL
goto waitloop
:endloop
echo Done!
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if this is the best way to do it, but i know it works 100%
I use call in my scripts when i need it to wait.

```
:INSTALLLAPTOP79
Call \ELAN\Touchpad\Setup.exe /s /a /s
Call \Intel\Chipset\Setup.exe -s -norestart
Call \Intel\Graphics\Setup.exe -s
Call \Intel\MEI\Setup.exe -s
Call \Intel\USB3\Setup.exe -s
Call \Realtek\Audio\Setup.exe /s
Call \Realtek\CardReader\Setup.exe /s
Call \nVidia\Graphics\Setup.exe -n -s
GOTO :INSTALLLAPTOPWIFI
```

Call will make the script wait until the exe that's being ran is finished.

Not sure what purpose the . before the \ serves but you may need it if its there for a reason.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. For an EXE-File, using `CALL` has no effect. It should be used for batch files to avoid exiting the main script. To wait for the end of an exe you should use `start /wait`, see the answer of @TripeHound

Comment: The `.` before backslashes in `.\Intel\MEI\Setup` uses the current working directory, dropping the `.` changes the behaviour to use the path as an absolute path

Comment: well it works in mine it waits for each exe to process but if i use start it doesn't. start /wait does work but call works for my scripts too it always waits. So your saying that if i remove call completely it would work the same ?

Comment: `CALL` has no logic to wait for the end of an exe, it would also work without the `CALL`. If you are using `start` the `/wait` option is necessary, else it starts the `EXE` asynchronous

Comment: i did not realize this, thanks. so how come it does wait for the exes when i use it ? is it just a default behavior of using nothing before it? if call has no effect then its the same as using nothing right? cause i haven't used start /wait  yet it does wait for them to complete. Sorry if this seems dumb but im not a pro and if i dont ask i wont learn

Comment: Yes, you can omit the `CALL`. It waits because your EXEs wait (probably console programs). `start /wait` can (but not always) can wait even for non-console programs. Asking questions is always a good idea!